# How to use a pivot table in Laravel to join 3 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have 4 tables - foods, food_categories, food_subcategories and categories_to_foods.

The same food item can belong to several categories and subcategories.
I can't understand how to get results in a format like categories -> subcategories -> foods.

Also, I would like there to be category_id and subcategory_id on foods array and category_id on subcategories array.

How do I need to set up relationships so I could use with() like this - a categories array with subcategories array (inside) with foods array (inside).

```
// I know this is not correct...
$categories_wiht_foods = Categories::with('subcategories.foods')->get();
```

```
categories: [
    {
        id: 1,
        description: 'First category',
        subcategories: [
            {
                id: 1,
                description: 'First subcategory',
                category_id: 1,
                foods: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        description: 'Pizza',
                        category_id: 1,
                        subcategory_id: 1,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

**Foods table**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | Pizza       |
+----+-------------+
```

**Categories table**

```
+----+----------------+
| id | description    |
+----+----------------+
| 1  | First category |
+----+----------------+
```

**Subcategories table**

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | description       |
+----+-------------------+
| 1  | First subcategory |
+----+-------------------+
```

**categories_to_foods table**

```
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
| id | food_id | category_id | subcategory_id |
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
| 1  | 1       | 1           | 1              |
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
| 2  | 1       | 2           | 14             |
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: *a categories array with subcategories array (inside) with foods array (inside)*, so your categories **have** several sub categories which in turn **have** foods? [`has-many-through`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) - or just use multiple `has-many` - from categories up to foods.

Comment: @BagusTesa I'm not sure how to do that when I am using a pivot table, can you provide an example please?

Comment: my bad, you didnt explain how the pivot table works on your question description (i didnt read that title, sorry!) and i thought the last table is `food` table.. may i know the reason as of why subcategory is not related to any categories if you expected the category has several subcategories which in turn has the `food`? how will you deal with the example data, will the `food` with id 1 will appear twice on different categories?

Comment: @BagusTesa That is correct. Food with id 1 can appear on several categories

Comment: sorry, to be blunt, i want to ask you, how did you know `First Subcategory` belongs to `First category`?

Comment: @BagusTesa because in my Pivot table there is an entry food_id: 1 category_id: 1 subcategory_id: 5